# jQuery ajax I need to change the value of a bool in the database form true to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I have a user class that has an active field of type bool, it should, when I press the button on the html page, change the active that is false by default to true. via ajax and jQuery. This is my attempt.

in code aktivan means active

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnSeeMore', function () {            // kada je kliknut button čija je klasa class = btnSeeMore
                                           // sakrivamo taj element

    // this je referenca na HTML element koji predstavlja kliknuto dugme See More
    // dataset je kolekcija svih custom data atributa datog HTML elementa iz koje uzimamo id
    // više o data atributima na: https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-data-attributes/
    let employeeId = this.dataset.id;

    var formData = JSON.stringify({
        "aktivan":true
    })

    // ajax poziv za dobavljanje traženog zaposlenog sa backend-a i prikaz na stranici
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/api/korisnik/" + employeeId,
        type: "put",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType:'application/json',
        data:formData,
        complete: function (xhr, status) {
            if (status === 'error') {
                alert("Something's wrong!");
            }
            else {
                window.location.href='pocetna.html';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So what isn't working as expected? You really haven't explained problem at all

Comment: @charlietfl It does not change my active in the database, and still to false when I click the button. I need to change this false to true in the database after clicking the button

Comment: The server side code needs to update the database. Are you receiving what you expect server side? Really not enough known as to why db isn't updated. You need to debug this in steps starting with is ajax sent...is what is sent is as expected, what is happening in server code etc

Comment: @charlietfl Don't throw me any error, do everything but don't change the active in the database.

Comment: OK but just showing us the javascript code is only part of the process to update the database. `$.ajax` does not connect to it, your server side code does

Comment: Hi, you are sending `"aktivan":true` ? how you know its active or not ? Is your server code checking that ?